# Default Credentials work in 1 project but not in another?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, file-upload, defaultnetworkcredentials

I have a web service that uploads documents to Sharepoint and works fine using

```
System.Net.ICredentials creds = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
context.Credentials = creds;
```

I have re-used this code in another project and I get the error:

```
System.Net.WebException was unhandled by user code
Message=The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

As far as I can see everything is the same in the config files and don't know why its failing. Any ideas?

Comment: @Priyank Please don't post any more edits like this one. It is a *bad edit*. You bolded/highlighted random words (incorrectly) while leaving numerous spelling and grammatical errors. Don't use `\`backticks\`` for highlighting, they are for inline code.

Comment: @meagar thanks for alerting me...next time i will not make this types of mistakes.

Comment: This might be an obvious question, but can you confirm that the service account of the second project has permissions to call the web-service? Also, are both projects ASP.NET websites? Finally, are you calling the same web-service from both projects?

Comment: Could you supply some details about the other project in which this code isn't working? Could simply be a situation where the service doesn't support the kind of authentication needed by The default credential (needs to be NTLM, Negotiate, or Kerberos, I think)

Comment: @RB Thanks for you comment. Im sure it has permission because if I set the credentials it works, but not with default. Both are ASP.NET projects. No, I am editing an existing service to now upload to SharePoint, using some of the code from a working service, but I cannot re-use that service.

Comment: @David W - What details would you like?  How do I set the credentials to either NTLM, Negotiate, or Kerberos?

Comment: Details such as what are you calling, what kind of resource is it, trying to determine if the same code should be expected to work as-is..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it for anyone who might come across a problem like this.

The problem is in IIS, it is using the default application pools. Simply change it from default to your custom pool where the "Identity" field is your PC name or Login Credentials. This can be done to the default App pool, however, if you have existing projects using this pool, it is advisable to create a new App pool so you don't break existing projects.